# Writing a function that matches id then checks to make sure length is valid

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a function that checks the id of what is chosen (matches it in my ids list) and then verifies if the length falls in between the min and the max. I am struggling greatly on this and any help would be appreciated.

```
    function getVehicleLengthByVehicleId(id) {
            const ids = {
                "77 Travel Trailer, up to 35 ft.": {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 35
                },
                "78 Travel Trailers over 35, License plate, not affixed to property": {
                    min: 36,
                    max: Number.MAX_VALUE
                },
                "51 HS up to 35' length": {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 35
                },
                "51 HS over 35' thru 40' length": {
                    min: 36,
                    max: 40
                },
            }
           ids.forEach(obj => {
             const min = obj.min;
             const max = obj.max;

           if (obj == id) {
             min = ids[obj].min;
             max = ids[obj].max;
             if (id >= min && id <= max) {
               alert('Yes! ' + id + ' falls in range');
               break;
             }
           }
        }

export default getVehicleLengthByVehicleId;
```

Comment: Where do you struggle? elaborate your problem

Comment: yu want to achieve it only thru react? coz it is easy with javascript .

Comment: ok I have answered it in javascript way. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Never define constant lookup object variables inside a function**

Coming to your problem
From your question I understand, you want to iterate over a set of Ids and find if the selected Id's length falls in the min-max range. For that you need length also as an argument to compare. Since you added *javascript* tag to your question I answer it with javascript way of doing it.

```js
var ids = {
    "77 Travel Trailer, up to 35 ft.": {
        min: 0,
        max: 35
    },
    "78 Travel Trailers over 35, License plate, not affixed to property": {
        min: 36,
        max: Number.MAX_VALUE
    },
    "51 HS up to 35' length": {
        min: 0,
        max: 35
    },
    "51 HS over 35' thru 40' length": {
        min: 36,
        max: 40
    },
}

function getVehicleLengthByVehicleId(id, len) {
    for (var i in ids) {
        if (i == id) {
            min = ids[i].min;
            max = ids[i].max;
            if (len >= min && len <= max) {
                alert('Yes! ' + id + ' falls in range');
               break;
            }
        }
    }
}

getVehicleLengthByVehicleId('77 Travel Trailer, up to 35 ft.', '20');
```

Hope it helps